# How to find div using id and data- with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

My html code looks like

```
<div id="1" data-level="level1">
<div id="replace"></div>
</div>
<div id="2" data-level="level1">
<div id="replace"></div>
</div>
```

I want to select `div("replace")` using jquery by `id("1")` and `data-level("level1")`.

Comment: ID of an element must be uniquue

Comment: You can simply use the descendant selector with id selector after using replace as a sclass `'#1 .replace'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Id must be unique. In your code id is repeating.

Use this

```
$('[id="1"][data-level="level1"] #replace')
```

**OR**

```
$('[id="1"][data-level="level1"]').find('#replace')
```

Answer (score 0):

This will select the required Div but if we are using id then there is no purpose of using data attribute also.

```
$("#1[data-level=level1]").find("#replace")
```

Answer (score 0):

in this case you can do it with sibling or by next selector as per below code

$( "#1" ).siblings("replace");

or

$( "#1" ).next("replace");

Answer (score 0):

You are having duplicate IDs in your code. IDs should be always unique. You can rather use same class and change markup to:

```
<div id="1" data-level="level1">
  <div class="replace"></div>
</div>
<div id="2" data-level="level1">
 <div class="replace"></div>
</div>
```

And then use attribute equals selctor along with find selector to find element by class:

```
$('#1[data-level="level1"] .replace')
```